# Lambda/default methods/type erasure quirk/bug using ECJ?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, type-erasure, default-method

Came accross this today and spent ages trying to reproduce/figure out what was happening. Can somebody explain why this happens or is this a bug with type erasure/default methods/lambda's/polymorphism? Uncommenting the default method makes it run fine, but I would have expected this to work as is

Output:

```
Works fine with an object
Calling consume
Hello
Calling accept with context
Hello
Calling accept via consumer...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method test/LambdaTest$$Lambda$1.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V is abstract
    at test.LambdaTest$$Lambda$1/834600351.accept(Unknown Source)
    at test.LambdaTest.main(LambdaTest.java:24)
```

Code

```
package test;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class LambdaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<Context> contextIgnoringObject = new ContextUnawareObject();
        contextIgnoringObject.accept(new Context());

        ContextIgnorer contextIgnoringLambda = () -> {
            System.err.println("Hello");
        };

        System.err.println("Calling consume");
        contextIgnoringLambda.consume();

        System.err.println("Calling accept with context");
        contextIgnoringLambda.accept(new Context());

        Consumer<Context> consumer = contextIgnoringLambda;

        System.err.println("Calling accept via consumer...");
        consumer.accept(new Context());

    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface ContextIgnorer extends Consumer<Context> {

//      default void accept(Object object) {
//          System.err.println("Manual bridge method");
//          accept((Context)object);
//      }

        @Override
        default void accept(Context context) {
            consume();
        }

        void consume();

    }

    public static class ContextUnawareObject implements ContextIgnorer {

        @Override
        public void consume() {
            System.err.println("Works fine with an object");
        }

    }

    public static class Context {

    }

}
```

Comment: The provided code works fine for me. I compiled using javac 1.8.0.25, 1.8.0.40 and ecj, launched using java 1.8.0.25 and 1.8.0.40. In all of these cases I see no exception. Which compiler version are you using? Probably cleaning the project would help?

Comment: Surely a compiler bug. That becomes especially obvious when you say that uncommenting the `default` method fixes the problem— as the compiler should *reject* that `default` method as it clashes with the erasure of other `accept` method (and the bridge method that the compiler ought to generate). Update your compiler…

Comment: Hm I've compiled and ran it with .25, .45 and .60ea b19, they all failed for me. Running on Windows x64.

Comment: @vincent_: did you really compile it with `javac` of these versions or are you using an IDE with its own compiler (i.e. Eclipse)?

Comment: @vincent_, rechecked again, also tried java9ea_b57. Everything works fine. Using Windows 7, x64, 64bit java.

Comment: Yeh whoops, I accidently compiled it into the source directory with javac but ran the ones still compiled by eclipse. Works fine with javac, I'll update my eclipse, thanks.

Comment: Wrote an answer just for the case if anyone else will hit the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears with older ECJ compiler (3.10.0):

```
$ java -jar org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.10.0.v20140604-1726.jar -source 1.8 LambdaTest.java 
$ java LambdaTest
Works fine with an object
Calling consume
Hello
Calling accept with context
Hello
Calling accept via consumer...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method LambdaTest$$Lambda$1.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V is abstract
    at LambdaTest$$Lambda$1/424058530.accept(Unknown Source)
    at LambdaTest.main(LambdaTest.java:24)
```

Using org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.10.0.v20140902-0626.jar or newer solves the problem. The Oracle javac compiler has no such problem. Thus the solution would be to update your ECJ compiler or move to the javac.